# ReactJS Form, how to get the image url in order to insert in mongodb database?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, reactjs, express

Let's say this form, once I click save, the first name, last name and **the file (the Image URL)** chosen will be inserted in database. How would I do this in react-js with mongoDB as a database. I know there's MERN (MongoDB, Express, React, Node.js) in order to submit the first and last name in the database. I'm wondering how to go for the image though, because **I need the Image URL's so I can loop through them and display all them on the home page.**

Image link is here (can't display because i dont have enough reputation XD) : [Image scheme of how the form looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oo4o7.png)

Comment: So, you just don't want to get the link right, you want to upload the image :) In that case, you should meet the image (or generally file) upload on the backend. Either you will write some code yourself to deal with `multipart/form-data` or you will find a library to do this for you. Just search around with this hint. Some say Multer is a good choice :) You will pass the formData from your frontend and meet this with Multer on the backend, then save the image, then get back some information about it, then use this in the frontend again, etc.

Comment: the image URL is just a string. the same way you save first name and last name you can save the url.

Comment: @SergioAlen Yeah i know but to get that image URL I have to use  a multer?